# Conditionally disable Windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET WebApi SaaS application where users have the option of being able to do HTTP Basic authentication or Windows Authentication.

My controller knows based upon some query string value whether to perform Basic HTTP authentication or Windows Authentication.

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (id == 5) // do basic for this resource only
            {
                return new BasicAuthenticationChallenge();
            }

            return Unauthorized();
        }

        return Ok("hello world");
    }
}
```

My current implementation for `BasicAuthenticationChallenge` is simply return a `401: Unauthorized` along with a `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="api"` header.

However, since Windows authentication is enabled, IIS decides to append NTLM and Negotiate headers, which causes the client to not understand the response.

```
... (response headers)
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="api"
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
... (response headers)
```

How do I get IIS to stop adding headers to my WebApi's 401 responses when I am trying Basic authentication?

Comment: You cannot unless you disable Windows authentication at IIS level.